# Why is my entity throwing an Exception every time I try to save changes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I have a web service which has info given to it via AJAX, my service then updates the current user's data as per what they've changed

My problem is, my entity keeps throwing an exception when i call `SaveChanges` as per the below message;

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

I have enabled optimistic concurrency, I also initially thought this was down to not setting the Dealer ID which is the Primary Key for my DB, but the dealer ID is fine so I don't see where I'm going wrong.

I've been able to update user info WITHOUT showing the info first, so I believe this issue relates to using the same entity to show the data, and also to update the data, but I'm not too sure

my code is below,

```
class Dashboards
{
        //this is my EF Model
        dealer DealerObj = new dealer();
   public void UpdateDealerInfo(string UserName, DealerInfoViewModel model)
        {
            using (var context = new VatsWebDealerEntity())
            {
                var UserInfo = context.dealers.AsNoTracking().Where(m => m.Name == UserName).Select(m => m).ToArray();
                var UserID = context.dealers.AsNoTracking().Where(m => m.Name == UserName).Select(m => m.DealerID).FirstOrDefault();

               //DealerObj.DealerID = UserID;

                foreach (var item in UserInfo)
                {
                    if (item.Name != model.NewValue)
                    {
                        DealerObj.Name = model.NewValue;
                    }
                    else if (item.Address1 != model.NewValue)
                    {
                        DealerObj.Address1 = model.NewValue;
                    }
                    else if (item.Address2 != model.NewValue)
                    {
                        DealerObj.Address2 = model.NewValue;
                    }
                    else if (item.Address3 != model.NewValue)
                    {
                        DealerObj.Address3 = model.NewValue;
                    }
                    else if (item.PostCode != model.NewValue)
                    {
                        DealerObj.PostCode = model.NewValue;
                    }
                    else if (item.Town != model.NewValue)
                    {
                        DealerObj.Town = model.NewValue;
                    }
                    //else if (item.CountryID != model.NewValue)
                    //{
                    //    DealerObj.country = model.NewValue;
                    //}
                    else if (item.ContactName != model.NewValue)
                    {
                        DealerObj.ContactName = model.NewValue;
                    }
                    else if (item.ContactTelephone != model.NewValue)
                    {

                        DealerObj.ContactTelephone = model.NewValue;
                    }
                    else if (item.Phone != model.NewValue)
                    {
                        DealerObj.Phone = model.NewValue;
                    }
                  
                        DealerObj.DealerID = UserID;
                        DealerObj.CountryID = 1;
                        var entry = context.Entry(DealerObj);
                        context.dealers.Attach(DealerObj);

                    //context.Entry(DealerObj).Property(e => e.DealerID).IsModified = false;

                    context.Entry(DealerObj).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    //entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `AsNoTracking`?

Comment: How you enabled optimistic concurrency? SNAPSHOT or RCS? Are you sure another process cann't change `dealer` record after you loaded it and before saving? Did you try `Reload` method as described there? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but try your `context.SaveChanges()` outside your `foreach` loop

Comment: BTW, you can write 

`var UserID = context.dealers.AsNoTracking().Where(m => m.Name == UserName).Select(m => m.DealerID).FirstOrDefault();`

as 

`var user = context.dealers.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == UserName);

if(user != null)
{ 
 var userId = user.DealerId;
}`